# Dropdown menu in Sharepoint 2010 Global navigation

Tags: sharepoint, navigation, branding

I created a new Blank site in SP. Before activating the Publishing feature, I added several links to the top link bar. However, I could only add a single level of New Links via the interface. So I deleted my links and Activated the Publishing feature.

Now I have the Global/Current Navigation settings page which allows me to create a heading/sub-menu structure of items, but they are appearing on the same level on the page--not becoming drop-downs. I have static and dynamic levels set to 3 in the nav bar code.

I don't know if having the links bar active first and then activating publishing afterward caused this. I started with the Starter Master page from codeplex--publishing version. Here's the nav bar.

```
<!-- top navigation publishing data source -->
<PublishingNavigation:PortalSiteMapDataSource
ID="topSiteMap" runat="server" 
SiteMapProvider="GlobalNavigation" 
StartFromCurrentNode="true" 
StartingNodeOffset="0"
ShowStartingNode="false"
TrimNonCurrentTypes="Heading" />

<!-- top navigation menu (set to use the new Simple Rendering) -->

<div id="BigNavBar"class="s4-notdlg">
<SharePoint:AspMenu
ID="TopNavigationMenuV4"
EncodeTitle="false"
Runat="server"
DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%>"
UseSimpleRendering="true"
UseSeparateCss="false"
Orientation="Horizontal"
StaticDisplayLevels="3"  
MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="3"
SkipLinkText=""
CssClass="s4-tn" BackColor="Cyan" BorderColor="Black">
</SharePoint:AspMenu>   
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm probably missing something obvious. It's the first "ground-up" branding project I've done.